# How to prevent modification in Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I add some utils methods to Object class:

```
Object.prototype.doSomething = function() {
   // do something
};
```

And now I want to prevent any addition to `Object.prototype`, is it possible?

Comment: You could `Object.freeze` it but...how do you know it wasn't modified *before* this? In fact, how do you know that somebody hasn't replaced `Object.freeze` with an empty implementation? It's (presumably) client-side code, so it's out of your hands. What exactly are you trying to do with preventing modifications?

Comment: **Note:** Your question suggests your code will be used in contexts that you don't control, e.g., as a library or similar. If so, I **strongly** recommend that you don't modify `Object.prototype` (or any other built-in prototype). It's marginally okay to do so in code you completely control (for instance, your own app), but doing so in a library is a very, very bad idea, as we learned from PrototypeJS and MooTools.

Comment: Is the `[prototypejs]` tag appropriate here? It's related to the Prototype *library*, not about native JavaScript prototypes. Confusion that has plagued the library since it was created.

Comment: isn't about control code, just to be sure that anyone (other developers) override by mistake those methods or add something else. in other world I want that all overrides writen in the some file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make the object non-extensible and make all of its properties read-only via [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

```
Object.freeze(Object.prototype);
```

I'd test thoroughly after doing so. :-)

---

Side note: I'd **strongly** recommend not using simple assignment to add properties to `Object.prototype`. Extending `Object.prototype` at all is usually not recommended, but if you're going to do it, make sure you make the new properties non-enumerable by using `defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "doSomething", {
    value: function () {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: `Object.freeze = x => x` that runs before this code will defeat it.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yes, as will any number of other things.

Comment: why we should make the new properties non-enumerable ?

Comment: @maroodb - So you don't break every `for-in` loop in the code on the site. :-) Even if there aren't any in *your* code, you may be using a library that has them, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so we need to add "enumerable: false" ?

Comment: @maroodb - `false` is the default value for all of the flags, so you don't need to provide it explicitly.